# useParams() for none route components in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, navigation, single-page-application

Please go through my App.js

```
<Provider store={reduxStore}>
    <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
        <Container>
            <Navigation /> <----------------------------------- HERE
            <div className="wrapper">
                <Switch>
                    <PublicRoute exact path={PATHS.HOME} component={Home} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
            <Footer/> <---------------------------------------- HERE
        </Container>
    </Router>
</Provider>
```

Navigation is use in all components so I added that component in App.js. For sure, this component has no route linked to it. BUT:

In **Navigation** and **Footer**, I want to use **`useParams()`**.

**Navigation.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import { withRouter, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Navigation = (props) => {
    const { slug } = props;

    return (
        <>
            <Navbar>
                <Nav>
                    <Nav.Link>
                        Home
                    </Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar>
        </>
    );
};

export default withRouter(Navigation);
```

My current url:

`localhost:3000/event/:slug`

I do recieve props, but I could not find **slug**

Answer (score 0):

try remove exact ?

```html
  <Switch>
    <PublicRoute path={PATHS.HOME} component={Home} />
  </Switch>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to my queries. Tried this solution, but still not working. It returned undefined.